# Directivas entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

Estoy en MVC 4.5 y estaba mirando el modelo de entity framework y estire una tabla para ver el nombre completo y guarde el archivo (realmente no hubo cambios). Pero en todo el proyecto donde hago referencia a entity framework me sale este error.

```
Error   2   No se puede encontrar el tipo o el nombre de espacio de nombres 'FormulariosEntities' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que coja bien la referencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he conseguido arreglarlo.
Abriendo el modelo - botón derecho -actualizar modelo desde la base de datos - pestaña actualizar botón actualizar y listo .